# Writing an interpreter for ANTLR grammar

Tags: clojure, interpreter, antlr4

I've made a grammar for APL subset.

```
grammar APL;

program: (statement NEWLINE)*;

statement: thing;

assignment: variable LARR thing;

thing: simpleThing
     | complexThing;

escapedThing: simpleThing
            | '(' complexThing ')';

simpleThing: variable    # ThingVariable
           | number      # ThingNumber
           ;

complexThing: unary      # ThingUOp
            | binary     # ThingBOp
            | assignment # ThingAssignment
            ;

variable: CAPITAL;

number: DIGITS;

unary: iota   # UOpIota
     | negate # UOpNegate
     ;
  iota: SMALL_IOTA number;
  negate: TILDA thing;

binary: drop         # BOpDrop
      | select       # BOpSelect
      | outerProduct # BOpOuterProduct
      | setInclusion # BOpSetInclusion
      ;
  drop: left=number SPIKE right=thing;
  select: left=escapedThing SLASH right=thing;
  outerProduct: left=escapedThing OUTER_PRODUCT_OP right=thing;
  setInclusion: left=escapedThing '∊' right=thing;

NEWLINE: [\r\n]+;

CAPITAL: [A-Z];
CAPITALS: (CAPITAL)+;

DIGITS: [0-9]+;

TILDA: '~';
SLASH: '/';

// greek
SMALL_IOTA: 'ι' | '@i';

// arrows
LARR: '←' | '@<-';
SPIKE: '↓' | '@Iv';

OUTER_PRODUCT_OP: '∘.×' | '@o.@x';
```

Now I'd like to create an interpreter for it. I'm trying to use [clj-antlr](https://github.com/aphyr/clj-antlr) with Clojure. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you need ANTLR? Have you explored Instaparse yet?

Comment: You need to write a visitor that evaluates the AST you get from ANTLR. @Jared314 - Instaparse looks awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jared314 pointed, take a look at [instaparse](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse):

This is how you create a grammar:

```
(def as-and-bs
(insta/parser
 "S = AB*
  AB = A B
  A = 'a'+
  B = 'b'+"))
```

This is how you call it:

```
(as-and-bs "aaaaabbbaaaabb")
```

And here is the result with default formatting:

```
[:S
  [:AB [:A "a" "a" "a" "a" "a"] [:B "b" "b" "b"]]
  [:AB [:A "a" "a" "a" "a"] [:B "b" "b"]]]
```

While ANTLR is definitely doing a great job, in the Clojure world you can remove all the surrounding glue by using instaparse.